# Form NoMethod Error in Rails using HAML & Sinatra

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra, haml

I've got this in my file interface.html.haml:

```
=form_tag do
        =field_set_tag do
          =label_tag 'speaktext', 'Enter text below or speak and the text will show there.'
          =text_area_tag 'speaktext'
```

I'm getting this error:

> NoMethodError at /
>   undefined method `form_tag' for #

I've searched Google with no real success. Anyone have a hint on how I can find out what the problem is?

UPDATE:
@matt pointed out that the Action Helper methods are not available in Sinatra.

Comment: How do you render this file?

Comment: @BroiSatse: Sorry, it's my index.html.haml file. In app.rb, there is:            get '/', :provides => 'html' do
  haml :"interface/index.html"
end

Comment: Is this Rails or Sinatra? `form_tag` is a Rails method and not available in plain Sinatra.

Comment: @matt It's Sinatra. That explains a lot. Thanks. I didn't see that in any of the documentation I read.